# Trouble installing ocrmypdf in google colab

Tags: python, ocr, google-colaboratory

I want to try some things out in google colab using ocrmypdf but I can't get it installed using the command **!apt-get install ocrmypdf -q**.
I can see in the logging that some websites can't be found during the installation.

Does anybody have some tips?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to install using `pip` by `!pip install` ? Let me know if this helps you to post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried that. 
It says "done" but with error:
ERROR: pytest 3.6.4 has requirement pluggy<0.8,>=0.5, but you'll have pluggy 0.13.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.

I gave it a try to import ocrmypdf and that also fails.

Comment: Weird. I did it with no problems. Can you share how you import it or what modules are beign imported please ?

Comment: I tried on a new runtime. !pip install still gives the two errors above but "import ocrmypdf" seems to work now saying "ContextualVersionConflict". I'm going to try using this package. I will let know if it's working or not. Thanks for the tip